# Using SVN through jenkins, getting error

Tags: jenkins-plugins

When updating in a job through svn plugin (the most updated one) I am getting the error "hudson.util.IOException2: revision check failed on ...... at hudson.scm.SubversionChangeLogBuilder"  sometimes. When this happend I am running the job again and then it works fine. Why it is falling on this error sometimes ? It has nothing to do with the SVN, since it works fine when running it with out jenkins. Does anyone has a solution ?

Comment: You'd likely have to post the full error message to have a chance at getting an answer.

Comment: Don't have a solution for you but looks the same bug I am getting and it is known to the developers. https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-31455